# How can I use arrays to loop through a collective set of variables I read from a file?

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops, each, watir-webdriver

I'm trying to make a loop so that during each loop it will take the name and password variables from the file and enter where called.

```
array = []
File.open("file_users.txt") do |login|
  login.each do |item|
    name, password = item.chomp.split(',')
    array << "#{name}" "#{password}"
    browser.goto "https://website.com"
    browser.text_field(:id => "user_name").set "#{name}"
    browser.text_field(:id => "user_password").set "#{password}"
    browser.button(:id => "login").click
    sleep(5)
    browser.close
  end
end
```

I think the main issue is trying to make the loop call the next set of email and password after using the previous ones.

*edited:
The result I'm trying to get is to pull text from a file, then give it a "name" and "password" value, then have it be entered into the text field on the browser when called...
for example, the text file looks like:

jerryname
jerrypassword
careyname
careypassword
britneyname
britneypassword

The result I want is:

```
#=> loop 1
puts jerrynamme
puts jerrypassword
#=> logs in
#=> waits, then closes browser

#=> loop 2
puts careyname
puts careypassword
#=> logs in
#=> waits, then closes browser... and so on.
```

The result I get is the browser opening and the name first being entered then the code just stops....the browser doesn't close, it just remains still.

Comment: `browser.text_field(:id => "user_password").set "#{passowrd}"` has a typo `passowrd` (I don't know if that's the issue but I guess that's a problem).

Comment: oh, whoops...yeah I fixed that in my code and it still won't work. But the password won't display when called. @Voldemort

Comment: Please post several lines of example text from the file. Also, what is your expected result, and what result are you getting? Is watir opening the browser? Does it do one loop and stop? Your question is too vague in it's current form.

Comment: yes, watir opens the browser. The (unwanted) result is it does one entry, then stops. Its supposed to grab two variables from array per loop. I tried to give the read text a different value: "name and password". 
And then have them called upon. @Beartech

Answer (score 1):

You say:

> the text file looks like:
>
> jerryname jerrypassword careyname careypassword britneyname britneypassword

If the file_users.txt file is as you describe, one line with a list of names and password pairs separated by spaces, the line

```
File.open("file_users.txt") do |login|
```

will return the entire contents of the file in first login value. The code

```
name, password = item.chomp.split(',')
```

will assign the entire contents of the file to name and set password to nil

You need to build a new "file_users.txt" file in the following form (note the commas and line breaks):

```
jerryname,jerrypassword
careyname,careypassword
britneyname,britneypassword
```

Then your code will be closer to working.

PS, this line doesn't seem to be used for anything and can be removed.

```
array << "#{name}" "#{password}"
```

Comment: Aw man, I thought the chomp would split it up and give each a value. But I'll look into it even further...and I'll remove the "array << ..." @Stevewilhelm